# Haskell "Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[a0]’"

Tags: haskell, types, list-comprehension, type-signature

Im doing a project in Haskell where I am trying to create a function which takes two list inputs and then returns a union of the list but without any duplicates.

The problem is that I keep getting the error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[t0]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for newList :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Here is my code:

```
allList :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
allList [] [] = []
allList x y = (x ++ y)

checkDup [] = []
checkDup (z:zs)
    | z `elem` zs = checkDup zs
    | otherwise = z : checkDup zs

newList :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
newList [] [] = []
newList x y = [checkDup z | z <- allList x y]
```

The first `allList` function creates a list of the two list, the `checkDup` creates a new list without any duplicates and the `newList` uses list comprehension to pass the combined list to the `checkDup`.

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Three minor notes that I hope will help you to learn Haskell: 1) `allList` and `newList` don't need their first cases. 2) You don't need `Eq` for pattern matching, so `allList` doesn't actually need the `Eq a` constraint. 3) If you remove the unnecessary code I mentioned, then `allList` is simply an alias for `(++)`. You could write `x ++ y` instead of `allList x y` in `newList`, and delete the `allList` function (unless the exercise somehow requires you to define and use it, or if you think the code is more readable with it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
newList x y = [checkDup z | z <- allList x y]
```

`z` is supposed to be a list you pass to `checkDup`, but in this case, `z` is just a single element

Maybe you want:

```
newList x y = checkDup $ allList x y
```

`newList` can be declared as follows:

```
newList :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
newList = checkDup . allList
```

Comment: Please always write spaces around the composition operator. If you don't, it looks too much like name qualification.

Answer (score 0):

Since @Smac89 answered your question, why not use a data representation like `Data.Set`?

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

allList :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
allList xs ys = S.toList $ S.union (S.fromList xs) (S.fromList ys)
```

(although the continued use of `Set`s is probably even more meaningful.)

Or by using `Data.List`:

```
import Data.List

newList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
newList xs ys = nub $ xs ++ ys
```

Comment: Yes normally I would but it is for a school project and we aren't allowed to use any imports.